# description item is not bold

Tags: koma-script, description

As the title says my description items are not bold and id like to have it bold and also an automatic `\hfill \\` if this is somehow possible.
Using:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,toc=indent]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{uarial}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item[Some Item]\hfill \\ with some Text
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Result is:

[image]

---

With the `style=newline`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uarial is not really a suitable sans serif. But if you really want you should use T1-encoding with it

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,toc=indent]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{uarial}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}[style=nextline]
    \item[Some Item] with some Text
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer. I was wondering why its not bold per default since it should if i remember right. Somehow the nextline seems to fail at a lager paragraph any hint fo solve this? (sure manuel newlines as in my question)

Comment: uarial doesn't work without T1-encoding, and so the fonts fall back to the normalfont. I have no idea what you mean by "fails". Show an example.

Comment: I'm sorry i added the picture by mistake into your answer and cant revert this ... thanks for the info i didnt know that i need the T1 encoding but as i read i should always use it per default i guess.

Comment: Should be added right now.

Comment: Solved it myself. Its because the item is to short so it wont get into next line. Adding a whitespace solved the issue.

Comment: `\begin{description}[style=nextline,labelwidth=0pt,labelsep=!]` should work too.